Javascript template related CVE
There are 2 CVEs related to go, shown by a scanner for my app:
https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2023-24540
https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2023-24538
Details dont mention any specific go package, but rather mentions javascript.
What exactly these issues mean in context of go?

html/template: disallow actions in JS template literals. This package understands HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and URIs. It adds sanitizing functions to each simple action pipeline

But I dont see any package mentioned.

May I know what packages you used in your project? like go/scanner or html/template etc.

I would recommend you to check this link - https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/482079. You can see the dependency tree their.

Actually its related to a go binary I have put in my docker image.

Both Issues affect html/template:
CVE-2023-24540:
“Templates containing whitespace characters outside of the character set "\t\n\f\r\u0020\u2028\u2029" in JavaScript contexts that also contain actions may not be properly sanitized during execution.”
CVE-2023-24538:
“Templates do not properly consider backticks (`) as Javascript string delimiters, and do not escape them as expected.”
If you directly or indirectly use html/template, upgrade your go version.
